# How to setup this layout

Tags: context

I am trying to replicate [this](http://www.rekenkamer.nl/dsresource?objectid=93091&type=org) page layout using context, but I am struggling.

I have read the context manual and tried changing parameters to see what happens, but I was unable to sort out the logic.

Can anyone give me some pointers?

Comment: Did you read [the wiki page](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Layout) as well as [the manual chapter on page design](http://context.aanhet.net/svn/contextman/context-reference/en/co-pagedesign.pdf)?

Comment: phg - Thanks. I managed to get the overall layout, but aligning the chapter/section numbers left is a challenge.

Comment: afaict left aligning the structure numbers in the inner margin isn’t directly available as an option, but you can [define your own placement method](https://gist.github.com/2709746) to fit your needs.

Comment: To align the number in the space occupied by `margindistance` use: `\setupheads[alternative=margin,numbercommand=\rlap]`

Comment: phg - I used your macro which gives the desired results. I also tried the numbercommand=\rlap, but decided not to use it.

Comment: @phg Please turn your comment into an answer, so that the question can be removed from the "unanswered" list.

Answer (score 3):

Aligning the structure number in the margin can easily be achieved by means of a placement method. These are ordinary macros that take two arguments -- one for the number, the second for the heading text -- and determine how they are typeset in the body matter context. This way the presentation of structurals is limited only by your imagination and TEX skills. For this to work, the setup key *alternative* needs to be set to `command` and the key *command* to your macro. Also, the left margin will have to be configured so as to match the required flush left alignment. (For further information see the structural rendering source, [strc-ren.mkiv](http://repo.or.cz/w/context.git/blob/HEAD:/tex/context/base/strc-reg.mkiv).)

```
% macros=mkvi
\unprotect
%% 1. Create a placement alternative, i. e. a dyadic macro. % ······· %
\unexpanded\def\left_margin_placement#number#content{%
  \vbox{%
    \localheadsetup\begstrut\dontleavehmode
    \ifconditional\headshownumber\inleftmargin{#number}\fi
    {#content}%
  }
}

%% 2. Setup the alignment within the margin. % ······················ %
\setupmargindata [left]            [align=flushleft]
\setuplayout     [leftmargin=1cm]

%% 3. Hook the new method into the structurals. % ··················· %
\setuphead       [chapter,section] [
  alternative=\v!command,
  \c!command=\left_margin_placement,
]
\protect

%% 4. ... Profit?
\starttext % ························································ %
  \chapter{foo}
  \section{bar}
  \input knuth
\stoptext % ························································· %
```

[image: Demonstration of flush left margin number for structurals.]

Comment: That should be `\c!command=...` rather than `\v!command=...`. BTW, how is this different from `alternative=inmargin`?

Comment: Compare the definitions (`strc-ren.mkiv`, l. 619): this one will actually respect the flushleft settings for the margin content. Thanks for the fix!