# How to move the chapter- and section number in ConTeXt

Tags: sectioning, context, chapters

I want to create a margin chapter- and section number in Context, like in the [offical manual](http://www.pragma-ade.com/general/manuals/cont-eni.pdf). How can I get this done?

This is what I tried for the chapter number.

```
\define[2]\PlaceChapter{
  \hbox{\vtop{#2}}\inoutermargin{#1}
}
\definefont[ChapterNumber][Serif at 90pt]
  \setuphead  [chapter,title]
  [
    after={\nowhitespace\hairline\blank[2*line]},
    command=\PlaceChapter,
    numberstyle=ChapterNumber,
    textstyle=sc,
    header=empty,
    footer=empty
  ]
```

The underline is too wide because the box under the chapter number is quite large. Furthermore, the chapter number is not centered in the margin.

How can I fix this?

Comment: You can browse through the source of ConTeXt manuals at http://context.aanhet.net/svn/

Comment: You could have a look at the answer to this question.

http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56040/how-to-setup-this-layout